# Part of the redux state re-renders (unnecessary) whole react component

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering

One of my redux state part (reducer) is `filters` reducer, used to store filter settings per page. It's key-object structure, so it looks like this:

```
{
   dashboard: {
     minDate: '2017-01-01',
     maxDate: '2019-01-01',
     //... other filters
   },
   otherPageKey: {
     //... other filters
   }
}
```

My dashboard page is big, but it contains `select` which value is read from reducer: `filters.dashboard.minDate`. Code that is responsible for connection:

```
function mapStateToProps({
  filters
}) {
  return {
    filters: filters.dashboard
  };
}
```

Now - whenever we select new date from that select component, whole `filters` tree is changed, so the whole dashboard component is being re-renderd. 
How can I solve this problem? Expected result is, that only `select` component, whose property is changed by user, should be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

More code would be helpful, but this is usually caused by the state or props being detected by a parent component (in this case, dashboard).

This can be caused by a few things.

- You're mapping to parent component rather than the specific child one. This means the parent component is detecting the change and therefore re-rendering. Is your `mapStateToProps` in your dashboard component as opposed to just in your select component?
- Improper use of `connect` or `mapDispatchToProps`. Check out [this post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/04/02/redux-rerendering/) for more information.

Again, more code would be helpful but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt! :) Give me a moment to explain this to you
// edit. I connected filters to parent (Dasbhoard) component, because in this component I'm using filters object, to map params - that are used to fetch data from API. So Dashboard also needs `filters` - but I dont know why my whole component is re-rendering.
So im using filters:
on component did mount, where I collect filter params;
on Select component, that receives current value from filters;
on function that is binded to select `onChange` method;

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're saying that your **Select** component receives filter options as a prop from **Dashboard**. And the `onChange` method in **Select** triggers a function that retrieves data from an API that meets the filter criteria (collected in you `onChange` method). **Dashboard** renders the new retrieved data and updates filters, passing them back down to **Selection**. Is that right?

Comment: You are right. One thing to mention is that my API action takes some time. But my Dashboard component is re-rendered (whats my problem) even when just filters changed. So... I Select a new option - only one filter option is modified, and the component re-renders unnecessary. That's that "wasted" render - not the one that is happening after my API call is completed/dispatched. Could you tell me what code you exactly need to analyze? This is a big component.